# Unable to ping the gateway in ubuntu 20.04 bond mode

Tags: network-bonding

I have ten servers, it has 2 INTEL 10GB network cards (dual port)

Under UBUNTU 20.04, use bond6 mode to bond 2 network cards in a group;

The server often fails to connect during the test

When the connection fails, through IPMI check, it is found that the server cannot ping the default gateway, but the machines under the same rack are normal.
When I set any network card in Bond to down, the network will be restored;

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

OS information

kernel: Linux stone 5.4.0-80-generic

driver: ixgbe

version: 5.1.0-k

netplay config

```
network:
version: 2

bonds:
    bond1:
        interfaces:
        - enp4s0f0
        - enp4s0f1
          # mtu: 1500
        parameters:
            mode: balance-alb
    bond2:
        interfaces:
        - enp8s0f0
        - enp8s0f1
          # mtu: 1500
        parameters:
            mode: balance-alb

bridges:
    br1:
        addresses:
        - 172.16.100.2/25
        gateway4: 172.16.100.1
        interfaces:
        - bond1
        mtu: 1500
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 8.8.8.8
    br2:
        addresses:
        - 10.14.100.12/24
        interfaces:
        - bond2
        mtu: 1500
```